# How do you add an AJAX call to a WCF web service to an ASP.NET web page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I see a bunch of examples online but I am confused as to whether the service should be stand-alone or in the same solution as the consuming application. Can someone please help me?

1. Do I need to add a file of type AJAX-enabled WCF Service to my ASP.NET web application or do I need a Web Service reference to my WCF Service?
2. When I use the jQuery Ajax function there is a URL parameter. All the examples I see use "`Services/MyService.svc/MyMethodName`".  Is this because the service is inside of the web application's solution?
3. Does my WCF Service have to have:

   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
4. Do my web service calls need to have the following attributes?

   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
5. Does my web application or my web service need the behavior set to `enableWebScript`?

Did I miss any required attributes or settings?

Here is my jquery ajax request in my web application:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://myserver/myservice.svc/mymethod",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: "{" + args + "}",
dataType: 'json',
});
```

Here is my web service web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Basic" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyServiceName">
        <endpoint address="basic" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Basic" 
                  name="Basic" 
                  contract="IService" />
        <endpoint address="web"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  name="Web"
                  contract="IService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  name="Metadata"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. no, you can call it directly
2. sort of. That is a relative path based on where the web page vs service are in your hosting environment
3. yes
4. if you plan to POST to the service method, yes.
5. yes, on the service

Include

```
   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

in your service endpoint behavior.

Comment: I don't understand #2. If my asp.net web application has no web service inside the solution but the web service is hosted on a dev server then what is my url supposed to be? Do I need to use an absolute address to the http of the dev server?

Comment: Absolute paths are always valid, WCF doesn't care which you use as long as they resolve.  In your case it sounds like you need an absolute service URL.

Comment: If I'm using JSON does my WCF service need more than basicHttpBinding? Do I need webHttp?

Comment: JSON will work across any binding, they are unrelated.  webHTTP is geared towards REST, so it supports the WebGet and WebInvoke options - so I think for what you are asking you'll want webHttp.  If you're building a RESTful service also consider using MVC if you dno't need SOAP support.  It's more straightforward.